# How do I fix this this prison script lua

Tags: lua, fivem

TxAdmin Log
[image: 1]

Server.lua file
[image: 2]

I have try'd to change the nummbers but I think in the Database is something wrong

Comment: You shouldnt post screen shots of code. Please edit your answer to include the section of code in text.

Comment: Error message says that there is no column `jail` in the table `users`

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to index `result` a nil value in line 170 of server.lua.

`result` is `nil` in this scope you you cannot do this `result[0]`.

Either find out why `result` is `nil` and fix it or avoid indexing it if it is .

Your code suggests that you failed to assign the return value of your SQL query to a variable.

So try

```
local result = MySQL.Asynch.fetchAll("...
```

Still you should checker whether your query actually returned a result using a conditional statement or assertion.